# Command groups (subcommands) using discord.py while using cogs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How would I use command groups (subcommands) in discord.py while using cogs? Would it be the same as normal? Normal meaning without using cogs? Or would I have to do something extra. I've looked over the discord.py docs but couldn't seem to find anything. It would be great if someone could show me an example of how I can use command groups with cogs.

I've tried the following:

```py
#This is in a cog
@bot.group(pass_context=True)
```

but my code linter keeps saying that bot is undefined.

When I try :

```py
#This is in a cog
@self.bot.group(pass_context=True)
```

Its saying self is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst in a cog, instead of using bot, use commands.
e.g.

```
@commands.group(pass_context=True)
```